# In Firebase Storage how to Link to existing Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

As the title says, my goal is to add an existing google cloud storage bucket in Firebase storage under the Add Bucket section.

I've seen some examples, when added a bucket, you have the option to "Importing existing cloud storage buckets", but I do not see this option when I add a bucket. Has it been removed? Any way to do this?

Update: I am on the Blaze plan. Also I'm sharing an screenshot of the options when I click to add a bucket. [image: Blaze plan]

[image: Add Bucket]

Comment: Could you please clarify what's your issue. Are you on a Blaze plan? Could you include a screenshot of your question. I can see "Import existing Google Cloud Storage buckets" on my end.

Comment: It appears I am on the Blaze plan, yes. I've added a screenshot

Comment: Is that the first time you'll set up your Firebase Storage? It seems that you haven't set up the default bucket. You must continue with the setup and after creating the default bucket, you'll see the "Import existing Google Cloud Storage buckets" when you choose the option to "Add Bucket" again.